# How do I change several broken URLs in a several wordpress databases in the fastest way?

Tags: database, logo

I tried and searched but not yet achieved.

I have a 167 wordpress websites on my host and for almost every website the logo URL is broken (pointing to an unavailable IP address).

I found the right table in the database under wp_options and tried to change the URL removing the wrong IP this way

```
http://x.x.x.x/wp-contents/logo.png
```

Became

```
http://www.sitena.me/wp-contents/logo.png
```

But this doesn't work, leading to no images in the header.

I am trying to find a way to solve this problem editing the database or using the CLI so I can do that in loop and not doing it manually through the backend for every site.

Sorry for my english, non-native speaker here.

Comment: `http://www.sitena.me/wp-contents/logo` is missing .png extension

Comment: Yeah sorry i'll edit my question, the .png was included and I didn't write it in the example

Comment: but what's the outputted URL of logo img after your DB edit ? does it return 404 not found ? or what..?

Comment: in the db the url is the right one (like the second one i wrote) but on the website the image is missing (blank logo in the header). After a while my theme replaces the url in the db  with "http://sitena.me/themes/secondtouch/assets/img/logo.png" and it shows the default logo in the website.